# Why does Google Apps Script's UrlFetchApp.fetchAll() not return HTTPResponse[] as documented?

Tags: google-apps-script

The documentation for [`UrlFetchApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object)) in GAS states that the type of value returned by `fetchAll()` is an array of [`HTTPResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) objects. In my testing using an endpoint returning JSON data, the value returned by `fetchAll` is a list of data objects that are the expected *data content* **rather than a list of `HTTPResponse` objects**. The following is my Code.gs test file:

```js
function test() {
  let oneRequest = {
      'url': 'https://rest/of/url/redacted',
      'method': 'get',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'headers': {
        'x-okapi-tenant': 'string value redacted',
        'x-okapi-token': 'string value redacted'
      },
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    };
  let requests = [oneRequest];
  Logger.log(requests);
  let responses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
  Logger.log(responses);
}
```

(I regret that for privacy reasons, I cannot give the full URL or credentials for the service to make a self-contained case here.) The result of the above in the logs is the following (with values again redacted, and the full result content elided to save space):

```
Jul 11, 2023, 7:51:48 PM    Info    [{headers={x-okapi-token=xxxxx, x-okapi-tenant=xxxxx}, muteHttpExceptions=true, contentType=application/json, url=https://xxxxx, method=get}]
Jul 11, 2023, 7:51:52 PM    Info    [{
  "items" : [ {
    "id" : "dade57d2-6162-4177-a4c0-f2d4d31e45f6",
    "_version" : "1",
    "status" : {
      "name" : "Available",
      "date" : "2021-09-15T21:33:51.302+00:00"
    },
    "administrativeNotes" : [ ],
    "callNumber" : "QB631 .S213",
    "hrid" : "it00001917823",
    .... more data fields skipped for brevity here ...
  } ],
  "totalRecords" : 1
}]
```

Note how the second log statement contains a list of one object (as expected), but this object is not an `HTTPResponse` object; it is the data that I would expect to see if I called `HTTPResponse.getContentText()` on a list of response objects, if the object objects were actually `HTTPResponse` objects. But as you can see in the code above, `getContentText()` is never called.

**What am I doing wrong?** Why is `fetchAll()` not returning a list of `HTTPResponse` objects?

I have looked at many examples of calling `fetchAll` on Stack Overflow, and it is obvious that for other people, it does return a list of `HTTPResponse` objects. But for me, it does not, and I'm at a loss to understand why.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you very much – indeed, you understood the question correctly and solved the problem! I want to take this moment to thank you, also, for your consistently helpful answers to GAS-related questions on Stack Overflow. I have learned a great deal from your postings, and have admired your consistent thoughtfulness and extraordinary kindness. I mean it sincerely when I say that I wish there were more people like you here.

Comment: Thank you for replying and I'm honored for it. I think that when I think of various questions for answering, I can also study from those questions. So, I always have a grateful heart. But, unfortunately, there are a lot of questions I cannot understand. I would like to study more for thinking of various questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About `Why is fetchAll() not returning a list of HTTPResponse objects?`, I think that when I saw your showing script, `Logger.log` is used for showing the value of `responses`. I thought that this might be the reason for your question.

For example, when `Logger.log(responses)` is modified to `console.log(responses)`, the following value can be seen in the log.

```
[ { toString: [Function],
    getResponseCode: [Function],
    getContent: [Function],
    getHeaders: [Function],
    getAllHeaders: [Function],
    getContentText: [Function],
    getBlob: [Function],
    getAs: [Function] } ]
```

From this value, it is found that `responses` is an object of UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse[]. Because those methods are included in [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response). And also, when the following script is checked,

```
console.log(responses.map(r => Object.entries(r)));
```

The following result is obtained.

```
[ [ [ 'toString', [Function] ],
    [ 'getResponseCode', [Function] ],
    [ 'getContent', [Function] ],
    [ 'getHeaders', [Function] ],
    [ 'getAllHeaders', [Function] ],
    [ 'getContentText', [Function] ],
    [ 'getAs', [Function] ],
    [ 'getBlob', [Function] ] ] ]
```

From this result, also it is found that `responses` is an object of UrlFetchApp.HTTPResponse[].

As additional information, when `Logger.log` is used, I think that each value might be shown with `toString`. For example, the showing value of `Logger.log(responses)` is the same as `Logger.log(responses.map(r => r.toString()))`.

#### References:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [Class HTTPResponse](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response)

Comment: This behavior of `Logger` versus `console.log` is unexpected (to me anyway). I had taken to using Logger.log because that's what I use in an Google Sheet add-on that I've written, and it simply never occurred to me it would behave differently than `console.log` when printing objects. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @mhucka Thank you for replying. If this is useful for your situation, I'm glad. Thank you, too.